# Copy line of text from input to output file while using xargs

Tags: bash, xargs

I have a working shell script that reads a text file containing URLs, each on a separate line. URLs are read from the file in parallel and checked for their status code where the response is written to status-codes.csv.

How can I write the original URL referenced from url-list.txt to the first column of output in status-codes.csv?

status-codes.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
xargs -n1 -P 10 curl -u user:pass -L -o /dev/null --silent --head --write-out '%{url_effective},%{http_code},%{num_redirects}\n' < url-list.txt | tee status-codes.csv
```

url-list.txt

```
http://website-url.com/path-to-page-1
http://website-url.com/path-to-page-2
http://website-url.com/path-to-page-3
```

status-codes.csv *(Current Output)*

```
http://website-url.com/path-to-page-2,200,1
http://website-url.com/path-to-page-after-any-redirects,200,2
http://website-url.com/404,404,2
```

status-codes.csv *(Desired Output)*

```
http://website-url.com/path-to-page-2,http://website-url.com/path-to-page-2,200,1
http://website-url.com/path-to-page-1,http://website-url.com/path-to-page-after-any-redirects,200,2
http://website-url.com/path-to-page-3,http://website-url.com/404,404,2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `-I` option. E.g:

```
xargs -n1 -P 10 -I '{}' curl -u user:pass -L -o /dev/null --silent --head --write-out '{},%{url_effective},%{http_code},%{num_redirects}\n' '{}' < url-list.txt | tee status-codes.csv
```

`man xargs`:

> **-I *replace-str***
>   Replace  occurrences  of  *replace-str* in the initial-arguments with names read from standard input.